# O que é Initialization Vector?

Tags: terminologia, openssl

Quando utilizei uma função em PHP, chamada `openssl_encrypt`, que criptografa dados, me deparei com o termo `iv`, que é *Initialization Vector*.

Eu gostaria de entender um pouco sobre isso;

Vi isso num exemplo parecido com isso:

```
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);

openssl_encrypt($texto, $cipher, $password, $options, $iv)
```

Eu entendi que o esse vetor de inicialização tem a ver com um valor aleatório, mas foi só apenas uma pequena percepção.

Queria saber mais detalhadamente:

- O que é *Initialization Vector*?
- Qual relação ele tem com a encriptação? Por que ele é necessário?

Answer (score 3):

No seu contexto o *iv* é um conjunto de caracteres randômicos, normalmente eles são usados para garantir que sua criptografia sempre seja única, e deve ser sempre gerado um novo quando for utilizá-lo, de preferencia nunca reutilizando um mesmo *iv* gerado.

Sua relação com a encriptação se deve que ele é uma forma de garantir que um mesmo texto não retorne sempre o mesmo *hash* quando for criptografado pelo seu método.

Vamos supor que vc tente criptografar o texto "Olá" sempre  com o *iv* *xpto##* ele irá gerar o *hash* *sahsau=7273*, e esse resultado irá está armazendo para todas as pessoas que utilizarem o texto "Olá", se alguma pessoa por acaso descobrir que esse hash gerado representa "Olá" ele conseguirar indendificar todos os textos "Olá" no seu sistema. Agora caso você utilize um *iv* diferente para cada vez que vc for criptografar o texto "Olá" ele irá gerara sempre um hash diferente, já que o *iv* é juntado junto com o texto que foi informado na hora de se utilizar a criptografia. Assim melhorando a segurança do seu sistema.

Obs: como um novo *iv* é sempre gerado, é necessário guardar ele também no seu banco de dados para poder utilizar na comparação de *hashs* ou descriptografia

Answer (score 1):

Como o Jeferson já respondeu, o Initial Vector serve para inicializar o seu vetor de criptografia.

Imagine que você tem um algoritmo que gere sempre a sequencia 1,2,3,4.
Para que ele mude este valor, vai precisar de um valor inicial diferente.

Normalmente os algoritmos capturam isso automaticamente de algum lugar (como o /dev/random em sistemas UNIX). Isso permite gerar um hash bom, mas é ruim para criptografia, pois enquanto o hash será gerado e nunca mais revertido, a criptografia precisa ser possível reverter.

Por este motivo, sempre que um texto é criptografado, você precisa informar um valor de inicialização, para garantir que aquele texto não esteja vulnerável a ataques como `Rainbow Tables`, ao mesmo tempo que tem que permitir a você descriptografar o texto.